Where does it say that Agamas are superior to Puranas?
The Shaiva-sarvasva-khandanam
https://ia802709.us.archive.org/13/items/shaiva-sarvasva-khandanam/ShaivaSarvasvaKhandanam.pdf#:~:text=This%20section%20of%20Nyaayamauktikamaala%20deals%20with
is a sectarian polemic written by Jagadguru Shrimat Vijayeendra Teertha
Shripaada in which he claims to have demolished EVERY act of praiseworthiness ascribed to Siva in the scriptures.  In "refuting" Lingodbhava, he writes

Explanation: In the Shaiva Puraanas, this story occurs which
mentions how Vishnu and Brahmaa competed with each other
for Supremacy and Shiva appeared in the form of an Agniskamba, an infinite column of fire, whose end could be found be
found by neither. The Shiva linga represents this rupa of Shiva,
also mentioned in the Skamba Sukta, but this particular story
contradicts Shri Vishnu’s Supremacy, which is known from the
higher Shaastras, especially the Vedas and Aagamas.

